# Can't view a certain website on my PC but can on my phone (same network)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dns

My PC and phone is connected on the same network and internet source but for some strange reason I can't view a certain website on my PC but it works on my mobile phone. I tried flushing DNS, checking hosts file, different browsers, restarting, still can't view it. Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: What error do you get when you browse to this domain?   Do you get a "page cannot be displayed" error?   404?  500?  Nothing at all?   What DNS servers are you using?   Is your router acting as a local DNS server or are you using your ISPs automatically assigned DNS servers?   I know your phone and computer are on the same network, but just try changing the primary DNS to 4.2.2.3 and secondary to 4.2.2.7 (both are public DNS servers) to see if that fixes the issue or not..  What is the URL that you are trying to access?

Comment: @Richie086 Yes I am using public DNS like Google but this appears to be an issue with my ISP, I called them yesterday and it magically worked today.